# Crystal Reports sumif

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to do a sumif here.
Lets say I have the following data

```
EMPNAME         TICKETS

Lindsey Abbott 102894
Lindsey Abbott 106402
Lindsey Abbott 105491
Alex Kenney    106337
Alex Kenney    106328
Alex Kenney    106338
```

The result would be like:

```
EMPNAME         Count of Tickets
Lindsey Abbott  3
Alex Kenney     3
```

How do I do this in crystal reports? Please help me

Comment: You could sum it in the query as well rather than the report. How many records are you dealing with?

Comment: 10000+ .... i cannot change the structure of already defined tables.

Comment: Not the table structure, but the query that you are making to get the data (e.g. view, stored procedure, etc.).

Comment: I cant change the query either.

Comment: @RyanGates How would I sum it in the query?

Comment: That is a separate question, but assuming you are using [sql server go here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

- Insert a group on `EMPNAME`
- Insert a summary field on `TICKETS`; choose `Count` as the aggregator
- Hide/suppress the Details section

Answer (score 0):

Your best method depends on what other information you intend to use in your report.  If there is a lot of other data, you'll want to research the use of Running Totals (a good starting point would be https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms227117(v=vs.80).aspx).

If all you are trying to do is provide a count per user, then use Group Expert and group by EMPNAME.  Insert the field into the detail section of the report. Right click on the field and INSERT SUMMARY. Summarize the EMPNAME field, calculate by COUNT, and be sure to check "Add to all group Levels".

When you click ok, you'll see the count in the newly generated Group Footer.  You can then simply move the EMPNAME field from the DETAIL Section to the Group Footer, shrink or hide the detail section, and you're good to go!